# In Sublime text, how do you disable increase/decrease font size with ctrl and mouse wheel?

Tags: sublime-text-2

With Sublime Text, is it possible to disable increase/decrease font size when using <kbd>control</kbd> and mouse?  I found the key bindings for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>+/-</kbd>:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl++"], "command": "increase_font_size" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+="], "command": "increase_font_size" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+-"], "command": "decrease_font_size" },
```

If I wanted to disable those, I could set the command to 'null', but how do you disable increase_font_size and decrease_font_size when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and mouse wheel?  I'm on ubuntu if it is an OS setting.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Found help on the [sublime forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3388&p=15914&hilit=font+size+mouse#p15914), should have looked there first.  But I will post a solution in case anyone wants to do the same.

I am using linux, but answer similar for windows.  Copy 'Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap' from '~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default' into '...Packages/User':

```
cd ~/.config/sublime-text-2/
cp Packages/Default\ (Linux).sublime-mousemap Packages/User/
```

Remove everything except font settings and change the command to null:

```
[
  // Change font size with ctrl+scroll wheel
  { "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "null" },
  { "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "null" }
]
```

Copy it into your User folder so settings don't reset after an update.

**Update for Sublime Text 3:**
This works with sublime text 3 as well, you'll just have to create the file manually subl ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap

Comment: This works with sublime text 3 as well, you'll just have to create the file manually ``subl ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap``

Comment: For windows because this question comes up as #1 in google.  Create a file located at `C:\Users\Michael J. Calkins\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap` and add the commands in the above answer then restart sublime.

Answer (score 9):

Linux:

```
vim ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/"Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap"
```

Set it to:

```
[
  // Change font size with ctrl+scroll wheel
  { "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "null" },
  { "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "null" }
]
```

Thanks to d_rail for the answer, just wanted to make it easier to do quickly.

Answer (score 7):

On sublime 3, linux:

```
cat <<EOF>~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/"Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap"
[
  // Change font size with ctrl+scroll wheel
  { "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "null" },
  { "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["ctrl"], "command": "null" }
]
EOF
```

Thanks to d_rail for the answer, just making it easier to do it quickly on sublime 3 :-)

Answer (score 2):

This was not working for me on Windows 10 (21H1) with Sublime Text 4 build 4107. I added the commands directly to the `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`, and also a `custom-named.sublime-mousemap` file. Neither change had an immediate effect and restarting Sublime Text did nothing to enable the changes.

I was beginning to suspect this may be a newly baked-in feature of Windows 10 and looked into disabling scroll wheel zoom in Windows 10 itself.

Google led me to a solution in a locked Microsoft Community [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-ctrl-mouse-wheel-scrolling-zoom-in-windows/d331fdab-8d5f-41ca-bf0f-d985bfdd5a59) in which the author mentions that this "feature" applies to pretty much every Windows application. I discovered that now even `Notepad.exe` has `Ctrl` + `Mouse Scroll Up/Down` zoom functionality.

The solution makes use of [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to disable the `Ctrl` + `Mouse Scroll Up/Down` text zoom shortcut. The post linked above includes detailed setup instructions. In that post, the author's script will disable the mouse wheel text zoom shortcut throughout Windows.

I added a context-sensitive directive that will disable this behaviour only while the Sublime Text window is active.

```
SendMode Input  
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe sublime_text.exe
^WheelDown::return
^WheelUp::return
```

`SendMode Input` is recommended by the AutoHotKey developers and the line is included by default in a new script from a Windows explorer context menu.

As this post mentions Windows, and after 6 years is still the #1 result on Google for this issue, I'm posting here in hopes of helping other Windows 10 users.